# Recuperar objeto con parametro tipo date JPA,JPQL,JSF,EJB

Tags: jsf, jpa, ejb

Buen dia, tengo la siguiente consulta quiero buscar un objeto por medio de la FECHA_ORDEN_TRABAJO el objeto ORDENTRABAJO lo recupero muy facil por su ID por medio de la siguiente consulta.

Consulta Entidad

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Ordentrabajo.findById", query = "SELECT o FROM Ordentrabajo o WHERE o.id = :id"),
```

Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EstadoBean implements Serializable {

@EJB
private OrdentrabajoFacade ordentrabajoFacade; 

private Integer idOrdentrabajoABuscar;


public Integer getIdOrdentrabajoABuscar() {
    return idOrdentrabajoABuscar;
}

public void setIdOrdentrabajoABuscar(Integer idOrdentrabajoABuscar) {
    this.idOrdentrabajoABuscar = idOrdentrabajoABuscar;
}
```

Iniciar

```
 @PostConstruct
public void inicializarBean() {

    tipoEstadoList = tipoEstadoFacade.findAll();
    ordentrabajoEstadoList = ordentrabajoEstadoFacade.findAll();

    ordenTrabajoList = new ArrayList<>();
    ordentrabajoListFecha = new ArrayList<>();
    ordentrabajoEstado = new OrdentrabajoEstado();
    fechaActual = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

}
```

Metodo de logica

```
   public void listenerBotonBuscarOrdentrabajo() {
    if (idOrdentrabajoABuscar != null) {
        String namedQuery = "Ordentrabajo.findById";
        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
        parametros.put("id", idOrdentrabajoABuscar);
        ordenTrabajoList =    ordentrabajoFacade.findByNamedQuery(namedQuery, parametros);

    } else {
        lanzarMensajeError("Debe Ingresar un ID de Orden de Trabajo");
    }

}
```

Metodo en pantalla

```
       <p:panelGrid columns="1">

                <p:outputLabel for="itidOrdentrabajo" value="INGRESE ID ORDENTRABAJO"/>                    
                <p:inputText id="itidOrdentrabajo" value="#{estadoBean.idOrdentrabajoABuscar}"  required="true" requiredMessage="Debe ingresar un valor"/>
                <p:message for="itidOrdentrabajo"/>                    
                <p:separator/>                    


                <p:commandButton value="BUSCAR" actionListener="#{estadoBean.listenerBotonBuscarOrdentrabajo()}"
                                 process="@this, itidOrdentrabajo"
                                 update="@form">                    
                </p:commandButton>

            </p:panelGrid>
```

Esta me funciona de forma correcta diferente si quisiera recuperar el metodo por medio de la FECHA_ORDENTRABAJO ya que no me genera nada ni un error ni absolutamente nada.

Consulta Entidad

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "Ordentrabajo.findByFechaOrdenTrabajo", query = "SELECT o FROM Ordentrabajo o WHERE o.fechaOrdenTrabajo = :fechaOrdenTrabajo"),
```

Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EstadoBean implements Serializable {
private Date capturarFecha;
  public Date getCapturarFecha() {
    return capturarFecha;
}

public void setCapturarFecha(Date capturarFecha) {
    this.capturarFecha = capturarFecha;
}

}
```

Iniciar

```
 @PostConstruct
public void inicializarBean() {

    tipoEstadoList = tipoEstadoFacade.findAll();
    ordentrabajoEstadoList = ordentrabajoEstadoFacade.findAll();

    ordenTrabajoList = new ArrayList<>();
    ordentrabajoListFecha = new ArrayList<>();
    ordentrabajoEstado = new OrdentrabajoEstado();
    fechaActual = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

}
```

Metodo Logica

```
public void listenerBotonBuscarOrdentrabajoPorFecha() {        
    if (capturarFecha != null) {
        String namedQuery = "Ordentrabajo.findByFechaOrdenTrabajo";
        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
        parametros.put("fechaOrdenTrabajo", capturarFecha);
        ordentrabajoListFecha = ordentrabajoFacade.findByNamedQuery(namedQuery, parametros);
    }
}
```

Pantalla

```
<p:panelGrid columns="1">

                <p:outputLabel for="itFechaDesde" value="Fecha"/>                    
                <p:calendar id="itFechaDesde" value="#{estadoBean.capturarFecha}"  required="true" requiredMessage="Debe ingresar un valor"
                            pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
                <p:message for="itFechaDesde"/>                    
                <p:separator/>                    

                <p:commandButton value="BUSCAR" actionListener="#{estadoBean.listenerBotonBuscarOrdentrabajoPorFecha()}"
                                 process="@this, itFechaDesde"
                                 update="@form">                    
                </p:commandButton>

            </p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para las fechas es bueno optar tomarlas en un rango, ya que la comparación de fecha se hace incluso a nivel de milesimas, así que el = no es tan efectivo, se puede usar

```
SELECT o FROM Ordentrabajo o WHERE o.fechaOrdenTrabajo BETWEEN :fechaInicial AND :fechaFinal"
```

ya el detalle hasta donde se quiera restringir el rango, depende de la necesidad que se tenga, que este en el mismo dia, o en la misma hora o en el mismo minuto, en cualquier caso coloca la fecha inicial como la que necesita y a la fecha final le suma uno segun el rango que necesite delimitar
ejm fechaInicial = 2017-01-01 12:00:00 fechaFinal = 2017-01-01 12:01:00

Otro punto que puede incidir es el formato en que la envia, asegure que la conversion a string se haga como especifica el formato en la base de datos

Comment: Muchas gracias eso era.